# ruby on rails code shows white text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am a newbie learning ruby on rails by watching udemy videos but i am stuck on a "routing error". the video proctor seems to have a different color text while he is using sublime so i am not sure what i am suppose to have? i am currently using a trial version of sublime. my code is below and see attached images. thank you!

```
class PicsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @pic = Pic.new
  end

  def create
    @pic = Pic.new(pic_params)
  end

  private 

  def pic_params 
    params.require(:pic).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

When i run server to see output result:
[image: routing error]
Image shows my code in sublime text editor:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[config/routes.rb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCTDl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Rails and SO! How are you running the server? What's the output of the terminal? What URL are you visiting in your web browser? Please include as much information as possible for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You try to access a page at `/posts`, while your controller and your routes file clearly tells that the path should be `/pic`.

Try:

```
http://localhost:3000/pic
```

Furthermore it seems like you have to fix our `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  root "pics#index" 
  resources :pic 
  get 'posts' => 'pics#index', as: 'posts' 
end
```

Note: That the naming convention for controller is a plural name in Rails. That mean you also have to make sure that your routes point to plural versions of controller names.

Comment: thanks spickermann for your guidance but it seems as tho the issue did not resolve by trying /pic but i did get a new error "uninitialized constant PicController"   the following is my code for routes.rb file.                                                                                                                      "Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :pic
root "pics#index"
end"

Comment: follow up...is there a reason why my text is white? in the videos of udemy the proctors text in sublime is blueish

Comment: You can configure IDEs to use what color you prefer. The creator of the video might have changed the default colors.

Comment: To be able to solve the `uninitialized constant PicController` issue, please post your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :pic
root "pics#index"
get 'posts' => 'pic#index', as: 'posts'
end                                                                                                                # i am new to stackoverflow but it seems like i cant upload files to this comment section but my code is shown above this comment. thanks again

Comment: @user3788836: I updated my answer to address the issue with your routes files

Comment: so i am not able to upload the file but i did upload an image link since i am constricted due to reputation points on how much i can post or upload. please see above for "config/routes.rb file" link. thanks

Comment: @user3788836 : I already updated my above answer yesterday to address that issue. Note that your `routes.rb` includes the string `pic#index`, but it needs to be `pics#index` (plural here).

Answer (score 0):

Much better, your controller name is Pics, you should have a `resources :pics` in your *routes.rb* file. Instead you have `resource :pic`. That's just a good practice, the error is that you are trying to access */posts*, rather than */pic*, or better yet: */pics*, once you fix your routes.

Comment: i tried your suggestion still no changes .....same error as listed in the description. i literally followed the udemy videos to the T and have triple checked my code. is there a reason why my text would be white and not blue as it is in the videos?

Comment: The error can't be the same, if you change your _routes.rb_ and restart your server you should be able to access your pics#index through _/pics_.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have router for posts. Go to config/routes.rb & add new line :

```
get 'posts' => 'pic#index', as: 'posts'
```

& url `localhost:3000/posts` will access with controller `pic` & action `index`

or

```
resources :pics
```

and  `run rake routes` to show your path look like :

`localhost:3000/pics` will access with controller `pics` & action `index`